# Monochrome vs grayscale in scientific journals?

Tags: color, journal-publishing, journal

Many scientific journals accept only black&white articles.

Does this mean that only monochrome (black and white only) articles or also grayscale (gray is OK) article are OK?

Comment: Recommend you try this question at http://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=journal for a wider range of answers.   And in particular for a given journal you need to ask the submission department of the specific journal.

Comment: Is this posting on-topic for this site? I fail to see any connection to TeX, LaTeX, and friends.

Comment: Definitely off-topic but: why would you want to use grey? Diagrams are usually handled differently as I understand it, but I can't see why you'd want grey in the text.

Comment: @cfr -- i think that the question about gray isn't about the text, but about figures.  full-color printing is expensive, so figures are usually converted to grayscale if not initially submitted that way; at least that's the practice at ams.